# Recyclerview won't show items, Firebase Admin SDK, Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**I**'m trying to retrieve some simple data from my database as an **Admin**, the data has been retrieved, but nothing is shown on the recyclerview.

In the other hand, i was trying to assign a value (String) from the database to a TextView, i was recieving the value, but the TextView was **empty**, i went to the `.xml file` and changed the **layout_width** from `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and it worked! Before that with the simple **Firebase Client SDK** it was showing the texte even with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

PS: Since i started using the **Firebase Admin SDK**, I didn't had any issues with writing data to the Realtime database, Or with creating Users. I tried both of them and they works fine.

**Here's the retrieving function :**

```
private void RetriveClasses() {
        // Get a reference to our posts
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Classrooms");

        mclassrooms.clear();
        // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Classroom post = snapshot.getValue(Classroom.class);
                    if (!post.getDeleted().equals("true"))
                    {
                        mclassrooms.add(post);
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    System.out.println(post.getClassName());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }
```

The `System.out.println(post.getClassName());` Shows :

```
I/System.out: L1 ST 2022-2023
    L1 ST 2021-2022
    L1 ST 2015-2016
```

These are the class names i'm looking for, which means the reading is succeed, but the recyclerview still won't show any items.

**here's my Adapter:**

```
public class ClassroomsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassroomsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context c;
    public List<Classroom> mclassrooms;

    public ClassroomsAdapter(List<Classroom> mclassrooms) {
        this.mclassrooms = mclassrooms;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.c = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.classroom_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Classroom classroom = mclassrooms.get(position);

        if (classroom.getClassName().length() >= 20)
        {
            String className = classroom.getClassName();
            holder.classroom_name.setText(className.substring(0,19) + "...");
        }
        else
        {
            holder.classroom_name.setText(classroom.getClassName());
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(c, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
                View eview = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.bottom_menu_classroom, null);

                eview.findViewById(R.id.Delete_Comment_Btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                        progressDialog.setTitle("Suppression");
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Traitement...");
                        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progressDialog.show();
                        DatabaseReference mRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Classrooms");
                        mRoot.child(classroom.getClassId()).child("deleted").setValue("true", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener(){

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(c, "Suppression avec succès!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                eview.findViewById(R.id.copy_comment_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final BottomSheetDialog bs = new BottomSheetDialog(c, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
                        View aview = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.edit_class_name, null);
                        EditText name_et = aview.findViewById(R.id.Edition_Comment_Input_Field);
                        name_et.setText(classroom.getClassName());
                        aview.findViewById(R.id.update_comment).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                if (name_et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(c, "Ce champ est requis*", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                                    progressDialog.setTitle("Mise à jour");
                                    progressDialog.setMessage("Traitement...");
                                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                                    progressDialog.show();
                                    DatabaseReference mRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Classrooms");
                                    mRoot.child(classroom.getClassId()).child("className").setValue(name_et.getText().toString(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(c, "Mise à jour avec succès!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            bs.dismiss();
                                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        aview.findViewById(R.id.close_edit_comment).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                bs.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        bs.setContentView(aview);
                        bs.show();
                    }
                });
                bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(eview);
                bottomSheetDialog.show();


                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mclassrooms.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView classroom_name;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            classroom_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.class_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: check if your if condition is true other wise no items will be added to the list and better move the notifiyDataChange out of for loop calling it after each add isn't efficient.
  if (!post.getDeleted().equals("true")) -> this better move the print log inside if block

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't have Errors with the code, But it supposed to show the retrieve items in the recyclerview but it doesn't, the data is there but the recyclerview keep empty.

Comment: @ManojMohanty The condition it's true, as i said, back when i was using the NORMAL Client firebase SDK i had no problem using the exact same method to retrieve data, but now with the firebase Admin SDK, the recyclerview keep empty even tho the data exist, and that's the issue.